# Getting stuck in a loop that slows down the application insanely

Tags: c#, visual-studio, loops, for-loop, console-application

Making a card game for an assignment in school, and I have come accross a problem.
In my "Start" method in my static Game class, I initialize some things for the game, where it seems to stop working.

```
Players[0].MyTurn = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < Players.Count; i++) //Initialize decks for all players
        {
            Game.InitializeDeck(Players[i], Names);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Players.Count; i++) //Flush decks for all players
        {
            Game.ShuffleDeck(Players[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Players.Count; i++) //Draw 5 cards for all players
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                Game.DrawCard(Players[i]);
            }
        }

        Thread checkPlayersHealth = new Thread(CheckPlayersHealth);
        checkPlayersHealth.Start();
```

After some debugging, it seems that it gets stuck in the "InitializeDeck" method, that looks like this:

```
public static void InitializeDeck(Player player, List<string> Names)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //A loop that creates 30 randomly generated cards, with 3 of each card
        {
            Console.WriteLine("asd");
            Random random = Program.random;
            int rNameNum1 = random.Next(0, Names.Count); //r for random
            int rNameNum2 = random.Next(0, Names.Count);
            int rHealth = random.Next(0, 10); 
            int rPowerNum = random.Next(0, 5);
            int rBaseDmg = random.Next(0, 8);
            int manaCost = (rHealth + rPowerNum + rBaseDmg) / 2;
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                player.Deck.Add(new Card(Names[rNameNum1] + Names[rNameNum2], manaCost, rHealth, rPowerNum, rBaseDmg));
            }
        }
    }
```

Card constructor:

```
public Card(string name, int manaCost, int health, int powerNum, int baseDmg)
    {
        Name = name;
        ManaCost = manaCost;
        Health = health;
        PowerNum = powerNum;
        BaseDmg = baseDmg;

        int numOfPowers = 4; //Amount of different powers excluding "No power"
        if (powerNum <= 0)
        {
            PowerName = "No power";
        }
        else if (powerNum == 1)
        {
            PowerName = "Heal any target";
            Power = new Power(false, true, 6, Program.random.Next(1, 4));
        }
        else if (powerNum == 2)
        {
            PowerName = "Deal 1-5 Damage to the enemy champion, and heal yourself for 1-5 HP";
            Power = new Power(true, true, 5, Program.random.Next(1, 4));
        }
        else if (powerNum == 3)
        {
            PowerName = "Sacrifice health from a minion to heal yourself 1-5 HP";
        }
        else if (powerNum == numOfPowers)
        {
            PowerName = "Drain HP from yourself to deal damage to a random enemy target";
            Power = new Power(true, false, 5, Program.random.Next(1, 4));
        }

        Thread checkIfDead = new Thread(CheckIfDead);
        checkIfDead.Start();
    }
```

It starts with running the loop 3 times, taking around 0.5 seconds each and after the third taking much longer, around 10 seconds for the loop to go through.

Clearly I'm missing something here.

Comment: How many players?

Comment: for a start, I wouldn't create a new random for each loop

Comment: @Orangesandlemons it doesn't, it reuses the `Program.random` instance, as i can see

Comment: Can you show `new Card(`?. What does it execute etc? does it load pictures etc?

Comment: if you comment out the player.deck.add() method, does it still lag iterations ?

Comment: Card constructor added

Comment: Seems like I don't get stuck if I comment out player.deck.add(), it worked like 10 minutes ago without me changning anything that has qnything with the card class to do.

Comment: Oh nevermind I found it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new Thread with an infinite loop in each for every card (30 cards for each player) wasn't such a good idea >:)

```
Thread checkIfDead = new Thread(CheckIfDead);
        checkIfDead.Start();

public void CheckIfDead()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (Health <= 0)
            {
                Dead = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just shows how much code sometimes needs to be put in the question :)